# Как тестировать View при использовании Moxy?

Tags: android, junit, mvp, mockito, espresso

Как правильно тестировать View в MVP, реализованном Moxy?

Хочется подсунуть ей вместо Presenter'а mock, но не могу сообразить, как это сделать? Во View у меня Presenter создается с помощью `@InjectPresenter`.

Comment: Presenter создается в другом месте. Аннотация просто указывает в какую переменную помести ссылку. Вы можете сделать инъекцию сами. Какой модификатор у вас стоит у переменной?

Comment: Переменная без модификатора (default). Я-то сделать могу, но как отменить инъекцию, которую Moxy будет делать сама?

Comment: А зачем отменять? Она вставит один вариант, а вы замените его на mock.

Comment: Может быть я не прав, но мне кажется, что тот презентер, который вставит либа, сразу начнет во вью что-то показывать, потому что и инжекция, и инициализация случится в одном onCreate(). Я бы поэтому хотел избежать такой схемы.

Comment: Inject презентера происходит в onCreate. Но аттачится она в момент вызова onStart/onResume. Поэтому можно после вызова super.onCreate подставить свой презентер. Либо можно сделать метод, который будет отмечен аннотацией @ProvidePresenter (https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/wiki/Provides-Presenter-and-its-Tag)

Answer (score 1):

Сразу скажу, что я не эксперт в Moxy. Этот ответ основан на изучении исходного кода библиотеки.

Вы можете поместить **mock** в PresenterStore вместо оригинального объекта и тогда при инъекции будет вставлен ваш **mock**. Получить PresenterStore можно вот так

```
PresenterStore presenterStore = MvpFacade.getInstance().getPresenterStore();
```

А потом используя метод `add` добавить ваш **mock**.

Comment: Я бы советовал, в случае мокирования через PresenterStore, в PresenterStore при вызове get возвращать необходимый экземпляр Presenter